# Does Malphite's E (the ground smash) work when his enemies are airborne?

Tags: league-of-legends

Malphite's ult temporarily makes the target(s) airborne. During that time, will his E (the ground smash) damage them, or would it only work if they are on the ground?

I would hate to think that I've wasted all these E's because I triggered it right after ulting.

Comment: All you have to do is check if they get the debuff when you cast them consecutively. And.. they do.

Comment: I'm relatively new to League, so I'm not quite sure what you mean by them getting the 'debuff'. Are you referring to the attack speed slow? If you are referring to that, how would one check if this? Also, regarding the downvote, some feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Using a search engine provides the results for what a debuff is. The debuff can be visible both by some visual effects displayed on enemy champion, and when selecting him and watching icons under his portrait. Also, i did not downvote you, but i am guessing whoever did it was because  **your question is easy to test yourself**. Simply make a custom game and ult+E. Check enemy minion hp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will hit. Attacks in the game are divided into  targeted projectiles (Malphite's Q, Ashe's Basic attacks), AoE skillshots (Malphite's ultimate), Semi-Skillshots (Yasuo's Q, Ezreal's W), Skillshots (Nidalee's Q, Ezreal's Q). The only thing that can stop an ability from connecting is the ability not being in the area of effect.

Areas of effect are calculated by hitboxes, which measure two axis, x and y. In other terms, it's what's for your character Front-Back, Left-Right. Being airborn only moves the character's portrait, the character will not be moved up (as there isn't a Z axis), hence that is why it will still hit.

Comment: EDIT: An exception would be from reworked Poppy's ultimate.

Comment: @drphil No, it's still the same. It's just a visual effect, while they're untargettable

Comment: Nope, Poppy's ult is different than all other knockups.  They can't be targeted or hit by AOE when knocked up by her ult.

Comment: Exacly, it's not a knockup.

Comment: What?  How is it not a knockup?  I've only ever heard it described as the instant cast is a knockup that they are untargetable.  http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Poppy

Answer (score 2):

It will hit.

Champions that are airborne/knocked-up are still vulnerable to every kind of damage in the game, so the AOE damage from Malhpite's E will hit them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, all area of effects skills hit airborne targets (i.e. : oriana malphite and yasuo ultimates, blitz fist, ...)